# Adobe Air as3 - Read XML file from desktop

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

How can I read an xml file located on user's desktop? I've tried this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var myXML:XML = new XML();
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/a.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
    trace(myXML);       
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `URLLoader` with local files, you should use a proper [URL scheme](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc7), like `file`, `app` or `app-storage`. The [`File.url` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#url) will give you the appropriate local URL, for example `file:///C:/Users/Username/Desktop/`.

```
File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('a.xml').url
```

Another, and often better approach is to use the [`FileStream` API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html), as it's designed for the very purpose of filesystem communication, also it supports synchronous operations:

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('a.xml');
var document:XML;

var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
document = XML(stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
stream.close();

trace(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently, this can be done by simply adding a '/'.

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/a.xml"));
```

change to:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("/" + File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/a.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to import this:

`import flash.net.URLRequest;`